# What kind of insert rates can I excpect from NHibernate with bulk opertations?

Tags: nhibernate, entity-framework-4

I am doing research on NHibernate and EF 4.0 and I noticed the bulk insert features NHibernate offers.
What kind of rates can I expect? and does EF 4.0 have a comparable feature?

Thanks, Jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't speak to EF's capabilities, but there is a [great article](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/08/22/nhibernate-perf-tricks.aspx) touching on NHibernate's capabilities when it comes to bulk insert operations. You'll note that SqlBulkCopy is still much faster, so this may be your preferred approach depending upon your usage scenario.

Comment: Excellent article, however it is done using a local DB which makes the results not so reliable

Comment: @Jason: True, but it gives you everything you need to run your own test in whatever scenario you like :)